# I'm looking for suggestions on how to properly handle the exceptions returned when I Ctrl+C out of the code. I'm new to Python/prgming. Running win10

Tags: python, exception, websocket, queue, python-asyncio

The following code connects invokes two websockets and repeatedly calculates and outputs a live quotient using one value from each feed.  I'm trying to figure out how to properly handle exiting the loops.  Right now I must hit Ctrl+C twice to exit the code.  The output freezes on the first Ctrl+C, then returns a slew of exceptions on the second Ctrl+C.  See below for code and exceptions output.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue(10)
    await asyncio.gather(func1(queue), func2(queue), func3(queue))

async def func1(queue):
    async with websockets.connect("mystream1") as websocket1:
        async for message in websocket1:
            json_msg = json.loads(message)
            await queue.put((json_msg["s"], json_msg["b"]))

async def func2(queue):
    async with websockets.connect("mystream2") as websocket1:
        async for message in websocket1:
            json_msg = json.loads(message)
            await queue.put((json_msg["s"], json_msg["a"]))

async def func3(queue):
    symbol1 = ""
    symbol2 = ""
    price1 = 0
    price2 = 0
    while True:
        key, value = await queue.get()
        if key == "X":
            price2 = float(value)
            symbol2 = key
        else:
            price1 = float(value)
            symbol1 = key
        if symbol1 == "Y" and symbol2 == "X":
            print(price2 / price1)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here is the output once I hit Ctrl+C twice.  Kindly advise how I can amend/augment the code to minimize/handle the exceptions.  Thank you.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
> return loop.run_until_complete(main)   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 603, in
> run_until_complete
> self.run_forever()   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 316, in run_forever
> super().run_forever()   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
> self._run_once()   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1823, in _run_once
> event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 434, in select
> self._poll(timeout)   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 783, in _poll
> status = _overlapped.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(self._iocp, ms) KeyboardInterrupt
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "testws4.py", line 54, in
>
> asyncio.run(main())   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 47, in run
> _cancel_all_tasks(loop)   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 62, in _cancel_all_tasks
> loop.run_until_complete(   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 603, in
> run_until_complete
> self.run_forever()   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 316, in run_forever
> super().run_forever()   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
> self._run_once()   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1823, in _run_once
> event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 434, in select
> self._poll(timeout)   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 783, in _poll
> status = _overlapped.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(self._iocp, ms) KeyboardInterrupt Task was destroyed but it is pending! task: <Task
> pending name='Task-7' coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.close_connection()
> running at C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py:1179>
> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at
> 0x000001A07EE7C940>()]> cb=[gather.._done_callback() at
> C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:769,
> shield.._inner_done_callback() at
> C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:885]> Fatal error on SSL transport
> protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x000001A07EE31F40>
> transport: <_ProactorSocketTransport fd=472 read=<_OverlappedFuture
> cancelled>> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 1179, in
> close_connection
> if await self.wait_for_connection_lost(): GeneratorExit
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 685, in
> _process_write_backlog
> self._transport.write(chunk)   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 359, in write
> self._loop_writing(data=bytes(data))   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 395, in
> _loop_writing
> self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' Exception
> ignored in: <coroutine object WebSocketCommonProtocol.close_connection
> at 0x000001A07EE329C0> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 1204, in
> close_connection   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line
> 317, in close   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 594,
> in _start_shutdown   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line
> 599, in _write_appdata   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py",
> line 707, in _process_write_backlog   File
> "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 721, in _fatal_error
> File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 151, in
> _force_close   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon   File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 508, in _check_closed RuntimeError: Event loop is closed ^C